# GUIs inside Operating Systems

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gnome, ui-thread

How do GUIs get built inside operating systems. Lets use two examples, say GTK+ in Ubuntu verses a Java JFrame. I thought that operating systems using some kind of graphical user interface would have to provide some system calls to be able to display windows. So for example, if I installed a version of Ubuntu on a machine, with out downloading any software I should be able to make a system call to display a window. It appears though that isn't the case. I have to install and download the SDK for GTK+ which allows me to create windows with buttons, etc. So then my question is with Java, how does Java then build it's JFrames? I understand that there is a Java Virtual Machine running ontop of the Linux system, but how does the Java virtual machine make calls to actually display the window? Along with GUIs comes the events that the user interacts with them. At the Java level, the JVM handles all the lower level calls, and you get OnClick() events etc. How does the JVM actually call and work with those calls? Same with GDK+? I understand this is a broad question with many different answers, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Uhh.. Your understanding of this seems a little bit skewed. First off, graphical user interfaces have 0 to do with the kernel (aside from KMS maybe), they live in userspace, and so does X with which GTK communicates. Remember that the JVM is just a userspace program as well, which I assume has X11 bindings for its GUI stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take Linux as an example. There are several layers:

- Kernel (Linux) and operating system (GNU) - Knows how to work the hardware, including graphics.
- Windowing system (X) - Uses graphics functions to draw windows.
- Desktop (eg Gnome) - Applies global styles such as window borders.
- (Usually) A toolkit such as GTK - Knows about widgets, how to draw them and how to style them.
- Your application.

On Windows, the Kernel, OS, windowing system, desktop and widgets are all bundled together. In this case the toolkit probably doesn't draw its own widgets, but uses them directly from Windows.

In any case, the toolkit insulates your application from the platform-specific details and automatically does the right thing.